# Deploy Docker environment on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I just "Dockerized" my infrastructure into containers. The environment basically is one *nginx-php-fpm* container which contains nginx configured with php-fpm. This container connects to multiple data-containers which contains the application files for the specific component.

I've seen multiple talks on deploying a single container to Beanstalk, but I'm not sure how I would deploy an environment like this. Locally the environment works. I got my nginx-php-fpm container using the `--volumes-from` flag to a data-container.

How would I create the same environment on Beanstalk? I can't find the option to volume from another container. Also is there a good platform that handles the Docker orchestration yet?

Answer (score 0):

AWS allows you to use [multicontainer docker](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_ecs.html).

You can use [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) to help you to create your nginx-php-fpm environment.